# Creating empty data frame with stringsAsFactors = FALSE

Tags: r

I am trying to create an empty data frame where the data will be strings and with stringsAsFactors set to FALSE.  It seems that when I do that, though, it does not remember the value of stringsAsFactors.

It works if I create a blank row, like this:

```
> df <- data.frame(a="", b="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> new.row <- c("a", "z")
> df <- rbind(df, new.row)
> df
  a b
1    
2 a z
> df[2,1] <- "q"
> df
  a b
1    
2 q z
```

But, I want an empty data frame.  When I do that, though, it treats the strings that I later add as factors:

```
> df2 <- data.frame(a=character(), b=character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> df2 <- rbind(df2, new.row)
> df2
  X.a. X.z.
1    a    z
> df2[2,1] <- "q"
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "q") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

How can I create the empty data frame without string factors?

Comment: Do you need to use a data.frame if all columns are character? This would work: `mat <- matrix('', nr=1, nc=2, dimnames=list(NULL, c('a', 'b'))); new.row <- c('a', 'z'); rbind(mat, new.row)`

Comment: I might be wrong, but that is a "process" option and not an attribute or something of an object. During data.frame creation, data are treated as you request with `stringsAsFactors`, then it is stored with a proper type. And as you noticed you'd tend to have problems if type can't be casted implicitly. You can't do what you want the way you want it do be done. You may convert each time assignment with as.character(), but it is likely that you are doing something wrong if you use strings and `rbind` often.

Comment: Thanks, using a matrix instead solves my problem, although I don't understand why having a table where all of the columns contain strings would be considered an inappropriate use of data frame.

Comment: While I don't know what is the bigger problem, but usually it is rarely needed to perform row by row operations involving characters. While you got it to work, perhaps, there is a better solution to a bigger problem that avoids such operations.

Comment: I'm just using it as a lookup table, where I want to bind a value to a key, where both happen to be strings.  The table will never have more than just a few entries, so a hash table seems like overkill and I expect would use much more memory than necessary.

Answer (score 5):

`rbind.data.frame` first drops all zero-row and zero column `data.frames`, and then coerces the remaining arguments into data.frames. This internal coercion uses the `default` value for `stringsAsFactors` in the coercion. (see the help for `rbind`, under `data frame methods`.

You can set this value by setting

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# now it works as you wish 
str(rbind(df2,new.row))
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ X.a.: chr "a"
#  $ X.z.: chr "z"
```

Comment: This will affect all subsequent treatments for strings and not a particular data.frame as OP requested.

Comment: @mlt `df2` was created without factors (by manually setting `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`). The issue is that it is a 0-row data.frame. Therefore, after s3 method dispatch to `rbind.data.frame`, it is dropped from the list of what will be bound together. `new.row` is coerced to a two column data.frame, and uses `default.stringsAsFactors()`, which calls `getOption("stringsAsFactors")`.

Comment: @mnel *which calls getOption("stringsAsFactors")* that is a shortcut from not providing that option every function call. My point is that it is not a "property" of a data frame, and data frame cannot "remember" that value as OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for an answer to this same problem and couldn't find anything, so I wrote my own function:

```
row.add <- function(x,newRow)
{
  cn <- colnames(x)
  x <- data.frame(lapply(x,as.character),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  x <- rbind(x,newRow)
  colnames(x) <- cn

  return(x)
}

df <- data.frame("a"=character(),"b"=character())
df <- row.add(df,c("A","Z"))
df <- row.add(df,c("B","X"))
```

Hopefully someone searching for a similar answer will find this useful.